# Team provisioning profile alternatives?

Tags: iphone, svn, xcode, profile, provisioning

I've got an iPhone app that uses push notifications, which means that I can't use a wildcard in the bundle identifier of my provisioning profile. This means that I can't use a team provisioning profile, which makes things difficult when several developers are committing code to Subversion.

When I commit my code, I also commit my individual provisioning profile settings in the Xcode project. Then when other developers do an svn update, they have to change the profile settings to fit their needs, and it's a never ending battle.

Is there a different solution other than a team provisioning profile that uses wildcards in the bundle identifier?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the provisioning portal, go to Provisioning and Development. Create a new profile and add the devices of your developers to it. If your developers only use the simulator, then just add your own device to it. Email the provisioning profile to your developers and all should work well.

Comment: Devices should not be tied with provisioning profiles, I think the solution to his problem is one of the answers to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760518/codesign-error-provisioning-profile-cannot-be-found-after-deleting-expired-prof