# Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'XX-YY-ZZ' can't be found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, provisioning

I am trying to use iPhoneDistribution...

When I do Build, I get the error Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'XX-YY-ZZ' can't be found  ...

How do I fix this?

What/ WHere is that XX-YY-ZZ ?

From my side, I have verified the App ID and used it in Info.plist as well as under Configuration > Identifier

What should I do now?

Please help me...I have tried all possible fixes on this and referred the Apple docs as well...I am totally confused and feel helpless now.

Comment: Does the profile show up in the Organizer under "Provisioning Profiles"?

Comment: Yes, it does..But just says "cannot be installed on device" which I assume is bcoz it is a distribution profile

Comment: Also I am not sure where exactly is it finding the XX-YY-ZZ...I mean where is XX-YY-ZZ referenced..is it somewhere in xcode settings ?

Comment: Sounds just like you have the wrong profile selected in your Project/Target Build Settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Project settings for the Build, make sure that the Release configuration is using the (correct) Distribution profile and that the Debug configuration is using the (correct) Developer profile.

Comment: ok..I did check the Release as well as iPhoneDistribution configuration is using Distribution profile and Debug configuration is using the Developer profile. Still get the same Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'XX-YY-ZZ' can't be found

Comment: If you have testndtv's problem, see this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1760738/96338