# How to revert a single file in Xcode 4 using SVN

Tags: svn, xcode4, revert

I'm trying to do what I think is very simple from within Xcode 4: revert to a previous version of a file in the SVN repo. I can see the version I want in the Version Editor. It even has the nice FileMerge like areas showing what's changed. What I can't seem to do is either revert to that version of the file (preferred) or even select the changes in the Version Editor view and have them merged (or unmerged as the case may be) from my current copy.

I really hope I'm just missing some menu item or button or something - this seems like pretty basic functionality…

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Apologies - revert != update to head. Answer amended.)

Unfortunately, this still applies to the latest version of Xcode 4: [Where is the 'Revert' option in Xcode 4's Source Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417687/where-is-the-revert-option-in-xcode-4s-source-control)

Comment: I don't want to revert to the HEAD - I want to go back to a previous revision. In fact, I haven't made any changes to my local copy, it's identical to the head...

Comment: Yep, that's the answer. I have to say though that the stackoverflow search in this case totally missed the mark. I search on those exact tags and don't find the link above in the first 100 results. Any suggestions on making searches here more effective?

Comment: Use Google. It's better at searching SO than SO.