# How to revert/recover .m file to a previous version? (autosaved blank by mistake and xcode crashed - no Source Control, no Time Machine)

Tags: xcode, macos, version-control, revert, savechanges

I've tried to search for the answer but I cannot precisely define the terms without falling under wrong threads all the time.

**What happened:**
Accidentally I've selected all the code inside a *file.m* and deleted it all.
It *became a full blank document*. When I pressed Ctrl+Z to UNDO it, the *xcode crashed*.

**The problem:**
When I reopened the xcode (after the crash) , the file was *still all blank* (**It was autosaved seconds before the crash as a blank document**) - *losing all my code*. *I could not use UNDO* to rescue me on this because it *autosaved and crash*.

**What do I need:
Is there a way to recover/revert my file to a previous state before this autosaving/crash?**

Extra information:
*Source Control:* I can't use it because the last "commit" was June 27.

*Time Machine:* Don't have external HD to use it. It is disabled.

Updated 1: I've pressed the button "discard last change" and the file.m reverted to the file saved June 27.
So, one more problem: Lose all the months of work up until now.

Update 2: I've found the solution, and posted below. But I need to wait until tomorrow to accept it as answer.

Update 3: I've reedited the text to clarify my problem.

Comment: *Reedited: apparently nobody understand what I was asking for. Sorry, guys. It was the shock.*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Oh! I fix it.
I've *opened* the **file.m** *with* **TextEdit**.
Then I browse to:
File > Revert To> Browse All Versions

It led me to a place with all saved versions of the file, where I could search with a timeline the exact moment I need.

[image]

I've find the version previous to the blank/crash moment, and copied the text, paste it at file.m on xcode( also saved, commit it to source control for safety) and everything is ok now. I could recover all my code again.

Comment: glad I could help. I know the feel, bro. haha

Comment: You are a beautiful person. Thank you so much for posting this.

Comment: This is awesome!  This gives you more versions, better granularity than time machine backup!

Comment: This should be the standard answer for 
xcode recover unsaved file
xcode crash recover unsaved file

Comment: This was my first post here and ppl was really not liking it at all in the beginning. After that I was really insecure to answer my own question and get banned or something haha :~~

I'm so glad this is helping a lot of people. :D

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!! Clever trick to simply open in TextEdit. Saved me so much time after I accidentally redirected `cat source > ./command.py` instead of piping `cat source | ./command.py` to a script I was developing outside of version control. Pheww!