# provisioning profil error

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Codesign error: Provisioning profile cannot be found after deleting expired profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760518/codesign-error-provisioning-profile-cannot-be-found-after-deleting-expired-prof)

I am new to iPhone developement, i im developing an IOS application in my iPhone, i test in device. but when i download an application from internet and i would like to test it in my iPhone, there is an error like this : [BEROR]Code Sign error: a valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.yourcompany.WhereIsMyPhone' could not be found

how i can do to test, the application of other programmers in my iPhone

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

In your `info.plist` change the bundle identifier to match the namespace of a provisioning profile that you have deployed on your device.

Comment: Thanks four your answer, but i don't now wath is the namespace of a provisioning profile

Comment: please, it's not clear for me, can you give me some detailed information. thanks