# xcode 4.2 project run on iPhone | Real Device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2, ios-provisioning

after I add **Provisioning profile** to my project and so select my device  and all. But now I'm getting error

`Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' can't be found`

do any now know why is that?

And Is their any good tutorial for replying my **Xcode 4.2** project to my real iPhone device.

Thanks advanced

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code Sign error: Provisioning profile can't be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758154/code-sign-error-provisioning-profile-cant-be-found)

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced such kind of problems and the best way to solve this problem is again create an App ID and a Provisioning profile -> delete the build folder of your app -> clean your project-> downlaod the profile-> double click on the profile, so it will automatically open it into the keychain-> Refresh it -> now drag and drop the new provisioning profile into your project -> Now in your project go to the info of your project in build tab go to code signing identity and choose the new one and remove the entitlements. and then try to run on device.

Hope it helps as it did mine. :)

Comment: you mean do it from the beginning? is it?

Comment: Sorry to say... but yes man... from the Beginning.. :).. but i hope It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the device and its respective provisioning profile into your Organizer? What do you see in the organizer when selecting your iPhone under devices? It should be there with the correct valid profile assigned to it.

Comment: Yeah. I added it. I can see it.