# Code Sign error with Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode4

I am getting this error;

> Code Sign error: Provisioning profile `'98745F54-634Y-882B-A56T-5EFE760C3EE6'` can't be found

I googled and found out that I have to remove this line from `project.pbxproj`. When I searched for `Provisioning profile` I get 6 hits. I need to know which line of `Provisioning profile` I should delete?

note: my xcode version 4.2

I went through a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758154/code-sign-error-provisioning-profile-cant-be-found), which shows a sequence of lines as in which line to edit, but I can't find that sequence in my `project.pbxproj`.

1.)

```
            PROVISIONING_PROFILE = "CC34F5T6-5765-465R-8VB9-FF98766D17H7";
            "PROVISIONING_PROFILE[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "DF98RRED-DE88-0986-869B-037B6345E664";
            SDKROOT = iphoneos;
```

2.)

```
OTHER_CFLAGS = "-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1";
                PROVISIONING_PROFILE = "CC34F5T6-5765-465R-8VB9-FF98766D17H7";
                "PROVISIONING_PROFILE[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "DF98RRED-DE88-0986-869B-037B6345E664";
                SDKROOT = iphoneos;
```

3.)

```
            PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
            PROVISIONING_PROFILE = "98745F54-634Y-882B-A56T-5EFE760C3EE6";
            WRAPPER_EXTENSION = app;
```

4.)

```
            PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
            PROVISIONING_PROFILE = "98745F54-634Y-882B-A56T-5EFE760C3EE6";
            WRAPPER_EXTENSION = app;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my knowledge you should not touch project.pbxproj file directly. Your error happended because you try to sign the application with a provioning profile that is not exist on your machine. Please do the following:

1. Go to Apple Developer Portal and make sure you have a valid provisioning profile.
2. in Xcode go to Build Settings -> Code Signing -> Code Signing Identity
3. make sure that you sign the application with a valid provisioning profile from step 1.
4. make sure the Scheme you use (Debug, Release) is signed correctly.
5. Clean the project
6. Build and Run

Answer (score 1):

I have heard directly editing that file has dangerous consequences, but I had to do it once for the same reason.

To find out which profile is valid, go in to the Organizer (WINDOW--> ORGANIZER) and select the valid provisioning profiles. When you select the profile, it shows up on top with PROFILE IDENTIFIER which is the code you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

On **Build Settings** search for **code signing**. You will find it.

Answer (score 1):

According to highest ranking answer of your [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758154/code-sign-error-provisioning-profile-cant-be-found) you should remove **all**
references to the old/invalid profile. You don't need to be affraid to manually edit project.pbxproj. Just don't forget two things to do first:

- **backup** your existing file
- **shut down** xcode before editing