# Xcode Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX' can't be found

Tags: provisioning-profile

I submitted a couple apps last week that were revoked by Apple. I fixed them and tried to sumbit these apps again.
I have been getting this error for two days. I erased all my certificates and provisioning files on the provisioning portal and created all new ones . Also, I cleaned up everything in my keychain.

I am sure I am using the correct provisioning file in Xcode's build settings, and yet I still get this error. Why?

Comment: A possible duplicate

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758154/code-sign-error-provisioning-profile-cant-be-found

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by the following steps:

1. Go to the file path where you save your provisioning file:

   ```
   ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles
   ```

   and remove all the provisioning files you have downloaded today.
2. Download the new provisioning file from the Apple member center that matches your project.
3. Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, rebuild the project, and see if this issue still exists.