# No Provisioning Profiles with a valid signing identity in xocde5

Tags: iphone, xcode5, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

When I try to use Xcode5 dp6 to run app on devices. I got an error of

> No Provisioning Profiles with a valid Signing identity found issue

How can I resolve this issues.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an Apple Developer Account?

Comment: Need More Explanation about what you have done.

Comment: I had the exact same issue, I tried all the usual stuff until I was total in despair and started to re-create my provisioning certs. The last did it for me, I have no idea why.

Answer (score 14):

All you need to do is:

>   1. go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles in the Developer Center
>
>   2. create a new provisioning profile in "Provisioning Profiles"
>     / "Distribution"
>
>   3. download the profile and open it
>
>   4. restart Xcode

And you can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7056660/1091539), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2241624/1091539) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8509545/1091539).

Comment: What does a Distribution profile have to do with trying to run the app on a device in debug mode from within Xcode?

Answer (score 9):

1. Close Xcode
2. Use keychain to delete your developer certificate and private key.
3. Use Developer Center to revoke/delete your developer certificate.
4. Use Developer Center to delete all the invalid development provisioning profiles.
5. Run Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > (Double click your team) > Refresh.
6. Xcode will prompt to submit a request to get a new developer certificate signed. (Choose yes).
7. (Optional) Have you team leader approve the pending certificate in the Developer Center.
8. Press refresh again to have Xcode download the new provisioning profiles.

You should now be able to select one of the Team Provisioning profiles to run in debug mode.

Comment: This worked in my case -- all I had to do was up to Step 5 (refresh) and then try again.

Comment: yes it works. but when you are a 5 developer team, you have to replace the certificate for everybody. thanks Apple.

Answer (score 6):

1. Goto Xcode **Preference** -> **Account**
2. Select/Add developer account.
3. Now click on **View Details...**
4. Click on **Refresh**
5. Restart Xcode

Comment: but not for me unfortunately :-(

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue and I manage to sort it by deleting provisioning certificate from Keychain app and I download it again via Xcode (Xcode -> Preferences... -> Accounts).
If it doesn't help try remove certificate and provisioning profile. After than make sure you set up everything right in Build Settings (Code signing).
Hope this help