# iOS - What is the procedure for updating a provisioning profile in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios

It seems like every time I update my provisioning profile, my xcode project still ends up pointing at the previous profile (I get "Code Sign Error: Provisioning Profile (long string) can't be found.")  This means I have to manually do a search and replace on my profile codes in the project as described here: [Codesign error: Provisioning profile cannot be found after deleting expired profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760518/codesign-error-provisioning-profile-cannot-be-found-after-deleting-expired-profi)

I have to think I'm doing something wrong as this happens every time... what is the procedure for adding in a device to a profile, exporting the profile, and getting my project updated with the new profile?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just delete the previous provisions from my organizer before adding in the new one with the additional devices just added.

Answer (score 10):

In XCode 5 you have to go to Preferences -> Apple ID -> View Details and then press the small refresh button to the bottom left. This will update all of your current provisioning profiles.

Comment: Thank you! This is the correct answer, the accepted answer seems to be too old... XCode 6 works this way too :)

Comment: Yes thank you, not sure why they decided to bury this functionality.

Answer (score 4):

1. (optional) Delete old profile in Organizer/Provisioning Profiles(if not used anymore, e.g only new device added)
2. Add New Profile in Organizer/Provisioning Profiles (Drag&Drop)
3. If you run Xcode 4, be sure to change profiles for project AND targets

... Sometimes you have to re-open project or even re-start XCode (don't know when or why).

Comment: If you got this error while building the project you should also "clean" it after installing the new profile.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE:

It turns out, it's better to *download the new/changed provisioning profile from developer portal and double click* it in Finder. Mac will install it in the right place and you don't have to do the acrobatic stuff in the bottom.

ORIGINAL:

For Xcode 7.1, you have to do the following:

1. Open **Preferences > Accounts**
2. **Remove** the dev account in question.
3. **Add** the account again.
4. Click **"View Details"** on the account.
5. Click **"Download All"** at the bottom.

This will remove all local cache, then fetch the profiles from the server.

I just had a blast with this when I tried adding a device to a provisioning profile for testing. Thanks for making it so hard, Apple!

Comment: I just can't believe what the hell is going on with Apples stuff?