# "[BEROR] Code Sign error" for one sigle app only

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, code-signing

The app I was working on suddenly stopped working on my iPhone, even though it ran great in the simulator. The error I was getting was `Code Sign Error: Provisioning Profile (long string) can't be found.` so I tried deleting the text according to [this tips.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760518/codesign-error-provisioning-profile-cannot-be-found-after-deleting-expired-prof) I'm not exactly sure what " Then reopen the project in xcode, go to the settings are reselect your new profile" means, but in my projects build settings the debug profile is set to the iPhone Developer-profile.

Now I get a new error: `[BEROR]Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution: <my name>' doesn't match any identity in any profile`

This happens only for this particular app (if I make new test apps, they run on my iPhone), and the app still runs in the simulator. I haven't downloaded new certificates and profiles, because they work on other apps (the affected app is the only app I have on the App Store btw).

Anybody got suggestions?

Comment: Same here, did you just upgraded to Xcode 4.3 as well?