# iOS Code Signing Error after App Name Change

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

Fellow Devs,

I used xCode 4 to develop an app called 'myApp1'. Now I changed the name to myApp2 in the xCode Project Settings, created a new provisioning profile in the Apple prov portal and downloaded it.

However, when I try to compile I get the following error:
Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'myApp1' specifies the Application Identifier 'com.company.mobile.myApp1' which doesn't match the current setting 'com.company.mobile.myApp2'

Apparently xCode thinks it still needs to use the myApp1 provisioning profile with the new app. How can I point the project to use the new provisioning profile?

Any help greatly appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: check the `Code Signing Identity` property in the `Build Settings` of your project configuration, maybe you are referencing your *old* provisioning profile in there

Comment: Thanks for the hint but the code signing Identity of the two profiles are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question contains the solution to my issue. The question is slightly different though.

[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760518/codesign-error-provisioning-profile-cannot-be-found-after-deleting-expired-prof)

Answer (score 1):

- select your project in the Navigation panel
- select your target in the main window
- select the Build Settings tab
- scroll to the Code Signing section
- choose the appropriate provisioning profile for the appropriate build configuration

[image]

Comment: If you don't see the new provisioning profile, go to Organizer > Devices tab. There select Library > Provisioning profiles and click the Refresh button in the lower right corner

Answer (score 0):

You can change your application name without getting a new provisioning profile. If you just want to change the name and keep the same bundler ID, use the existing provisioning profile. When the user updates the app this way, their `MyApp1` will be replaced with `MyApp2`.