# How to change my provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution, adhoc

I wanted to add a new beta tester today so updated my provisioning profile to include them. When I attempted to run my app an error appeared saying my profile '*' did not match my profile 'com.HUDKING'. I deleted my old profile and my bundle identifier to check this was not the cause and altered my codesigning as shown below.

When I attempt to archive my app I get the following error:
*Provisioning profile '259FB85E-9614-4A3A-9987-9F4619BA2F9B' can't be found*

None of my profiles appear to have this identifier, I've set them all manually to ensure the right profiles are selected:
[image]

How do I fix this? Is there an easier way to run a beta test?

Comment: This worked for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1760738/957245

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like Xcode is still trying to use your old profile, it remembers the ID it was using previously.

the best answer is to change all of your code signing identities to be the automatically selected entries. otherwise just changing the selected identity and setting to the new profile should work.

Comment: I have changed them all manually to ensure the correct ones are selected. What I assume is my old profile appears to be being used anyway.

Comment: The identifier in the error looks far longer than the identifier in the code signing entry. I suspect their different things.

Comment: have you tried deleting the profile's from organizer and re-downloading just the newest copy? the profile ID its referring to is something like profile version ID, the Developer ID that doesn't change

Comment: Ye I tried this I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this earlier today. Try this...

1. Download the new Prov Profile & install it to Organizer
2. Go into Organizer and remove all old instances of the Prov Profile tied to that bundle identifier
3. Build the code (it will fail)
4. Change the code signing identity to "Don't Sign" (it will fail again)
5. Clean the build (SHIFT+CMD+K)
6. Change the code signing identity to the Prov Profile you just downloaded
7. Build the code again (it should pass)

Comment: Strangely enough even when I had code signing disabled it still gave me the same error, that provisioning profile '259..' could not be found.

Comment: Are you trying to compile to Debug or Distribution?

Comment: An ad-hoc build for my beta testers.

Comment: what's Organizer?