# Xcode Provisioning profile apple id not matching bundle identifier

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting an error

> "No matching provisioning profiles"

where it says the AppleID has to be the same as the bundle identifier.

The problem is that it IS the same, but when I create my project, it adds "Tests" to the end of the bundle identifier.

For example, AppID is "com.company.app". I create a project with the Product Name "app" and the Organization Identifier "com.company". The Bundle Identifier is then set to "com.company.app".

When I try to run it on my device it says that the AppID is ""com.company.app" but the bundle identifier is "com.company.appTests"

Comment: It does not say "the Apple ID has to be the same as the Bundle Identifier" - that makes no sense. What is the actual error message that you get?

Comment: The provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“APP.ADHOC”) has an AppID of “com.companyexample.app” which does not match your bundle identifier “com.companyexample.appTests”.  Xcode can resolve this issue by downloading a new provisioning profile from the Member Center.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1760738/3535399) answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: `Tests`'s code signing is `none required`, so just set its Debug's `Provisioning Profile` to Automatic and set its `Code signing Identity` to `iOS Developer`, which actually means no code signing.

Answer (score 12):

make sure your code signing identity is correct for the appTests target.

I usually get that when code signing is set to the wrong profile in Tests target. Try to set it to correct profile or try `Dont Code Sign`

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was able to get it to work by setting all the Code Signing Identities for both targets and the project to "iOS Developer" and the Provisioning Profile to "Automatic"

But I have a few questions, I tend to not have much faith in things being done automatically. I created 1 adhoc (ios distribution) PP for this app. When I set that PP (instead of automatic), the code signing identities get changed to iPhone Developer. This is when I get the error message that I pasted to Stefan Arentz's comment above.

Comment: Adding to the above, when I change the signing identities to "iPhone Distribution *name* (*prefix*)", I get the same error. I did this because I created an adhoc (DISTRIBUTION) PP, not a development PP.

Sorry for all the questions but i've never submitted an app and it hasn't always been the most straightforward process.

Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: You have to have a development profile if you want to deploy your app directly to your device using cable.  Adhoc/in-house distribution profile is used for Release section of code signing and needed when you package your app to .ipa format. So if you are doing adhoc development you need a development certificate for yourself, then App ID for each app and a development and a distribution profile for each app. And for both your app target and testtarget's code signing they need to match.

Comment: `Don't Code Sign` is correct. I'm using Xcode 8.1, and your answer works for me.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you a lot! Lost an entire day trying to just BUILD my project. These configs are ridiculously complicated.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Build section of xcode, search for bundle identifier and change that to what your app id is and error will be gone

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by **restarting** my phone after **uninstalling** the app. You can give it a try.